# html2canvas screenshots differ from original

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas in order to take screenshots of my page but i noticed that the screenshots differ from the original.

Here is an example:

[image: Original]

[image: Screenshot]

The first one is the original and the second one is the screenshot.

I noticed this issue on multiple other elements aswell.

Here is a minimal example of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/2j9pcz3h/

```
html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

The screenshot is appended to the body.

Anyone elese had the same issue and know how to fix it?

Comment: html2canvas is not almighty. Perhaps there's more info in the DOCS about what are the pros/cons of the available methods and supported CSS features.

Comment: Also, why not provide a [mcve] of the above issue? Please read [ask]

Comment: When you convert from HTML to canvas does any message appear in your console? something like "access blocked" or "cross origin" or anything?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i added a small example to reproduce the issue.